# testing if an element of a dataframe is a string in r

Tags: r, string, dataframe, subset, numeric

I'm trying to manage a large data frame with r. I want to subset only rows with a number on the first cell (participants), and get rid of rows starting with a characters (testing trials).

I've simplified my issue below. Here, I try to obtain a data frame with only the first and the last row.

```
a <- c("2", "s", "6")
b <- c("1", "2", "3")
x <- data.frame(a, b)

new_x <- x[which(is.numeric(x$a)), ]
```

But this way, my new data frame is empty. I've also tried using

```
for (r in 1:nrow(x)){
 row <- x[r,]
 if (is.numeric(row[,1])){
  #then built a new df
}}
```

which is not working either. How should I do?

Comment: `x[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(x$a))),]`

Comment: You might also consider setting your first column as "true" numeric column via `data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: The !is.na solution works, although R yields warning messages when introducing NAs by coercion. However, setting the column as numeric with stringsAsFactors = FALSE as suggested by @Manuel doesn't.

Comment: Forgot, had overseen that you specify your numbers as characters by using quotes. To get "real" numbers you need to do `b <- c(1, 2, 3)`without quotes. Otherwise you could still turn your whole character column into numeric via `x$b <- as.numeric(x$b)`.